# Fitting of GLM with statsmodels

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

Python's `statsmodels` module offers a set of methods to estimate `GLM` as illustrated in https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/glm.html

e.g.

```
glm_binom = sm.GLM(data.endog, data.exog, family=sm.families.Binomial())
```

What is the link function in above example? Is it `logit` link? How can I use other link like `loglog`?

I tried below without any success

```
glm_binom = sm.GLM(data.endog, data.exog, family=sm.families.Binomial(link = 'loglog'))
```

Any pointer will be very helpful

Comment: link keyword requires an instance of a link class, e.g. `family=sm.families.Binomial(link=sm.families.links.loglog()` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest statsmodels stable release (currently *v0.13.2*), only the following link functions are available for each `sm.families.family`:

| **Family** | **ident** | **log** | **logit** | **probit** | **cloglog** | **pow** | **opow** | **nbinom** | **loglog** | **logc** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Gaussian** | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |  |
| **Inv Gaussian** | X | X |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |
| **Binomial** | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |  | X | X |
| **Poisson** | X | X |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |
| **Neg Binomial** | X | X |  |  |  | X |  | X |  |  |
| **Gamma** | X | X |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |
| **Tweedie** | X | X |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |

Alternatively, the list of available link functions can be obtained by:

```
sm.families.family.<familyname>.links
```

Lastly, in order to change the default link function of the GLM in statsmodels you need to specify the `link` parameter in the `family` parameter:

```
sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Binomial(link=sm.families.links.loglog()))
```

P.S. The default link for the Binomial family is the logit link.